# JUnit output does not include Gherkin pre-fixes

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I'm new to this so excuse me if this is an obvious question...

I'm running a JUnit test in Eclipse using a cucumber framework.  I have arrived at a point where everything is now working, however, the JUnit output does not prefix the entries with the Gherkin descriptions, i.e. Scenario:, Given:, Then:, When:, etc.  Every example I've found online, they just seem to be there as standard.

I've tried adding a multitude of different jar files (just in case I was missing something specific) with no success, and I've also run through all the obvious preferences/config settings but it's just not happening.

The version of eclipse I'm using is - Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), Build id: 20170314-1500
with JUnit4

Not sure if anyone can assist? but if you need any other information please let me know as I've hit a bit of a brick wall....

Many thanks
Carl

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: The Cucumber Eclipse plugin I have is 1.0.0.202003111437 and for the most part, all '.jar' files are 5.5.0 (core, gherkin, java, plugin) with the exceptions being; cucumber-expressions (8.3.1), cucumber-html (0.2.7), cucumber-jvm-deps (1.0.6) and cucumber-tag-expressions (2.0.3) as these were the most recent.  Hopefully that's the information you need... thanks

Comment: This will not solve ur issue but u cld just include cucumber-java & cucumber-junit dependencies. Rest will be pulled in. Is it the junit console with the green-red progress bars or the standard console. If it is the second one, then u need to add the 'pretty' plugin to cucumberoptions.

Comment: @Grasshopper I'm happy I have both of those in place.  It's just the output in the JUnit window.  This shows 'The login will be successful', however, the Console output is 'Then The login will be successful'?